# VB.NET - is it possible to open / run a webrequest from a text file?

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I have about 50 web requests that are saved on .txt files on my desktop. Is it possible to open and run each of those web request from a folder after my program has been compiled or do they have to be compiled before hand?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean URLs in a text file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it possible.  Create an EXE that reads the file and opens the urls.  Add this as a post build step.